# Why can't I query by String value when I can query by equivalent int value in Hibernate JPA with java

Tags: java, hibernate

I was given a project at work including JPA / Hibernate

I have an object for example that is let s say described as

```
class SampleObject {
   string value;
   string othervalue;
}
```

and lets say that the value in the database is populated with 2 rows

table - SampleObject

- row 1 - value = "21", othervalue = "some other value"
- row 2 - value = "31", othervalue = "some other other value"

I can write a query that returns rows that follows

```
Query q = entityManager.createQuery("select s from SampleObject s where value = 21")
```

and I can write a query that returns rows that follows

```
Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from dbo.SampleObject s where value = 21", SampleObject.class)
```

but what i cannot do is write those same queries as a string value and return data

ex 1:

```
  entityManager.createQuery("select s from SampleObject s where value = '21'")
```

ex 2:

```
  entityManager.createQuery("select s from SampleObject s where value = :val").setParameter("val", "21")
```

ex 3:

```
   entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from dbo.SampleObject s where value = '21'", SampleObject.class)
```

but as you can see this is stored as a varchar and IS REQUIRED to remain a string so i need to be able to query by a string

Disclaimer:

I am new to hibernate - very new .... very very new!

I should add in SQL SSMS I can directly query by string

I also tried using one of the suggestions below and for context it didn't resolve
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
            .createQuery("<your query>")
            .setParameter("identifier", "3", StringType.INSTANCE);
```

That implementation works with the exact type that you want to pass.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't resolve

i am looking for a reasonable function signature for a candidate and havent found one yet

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have to apologize I had an old connection string

and I was directly querying the current data  in ssms and the connection string was grabbing old data in the java

my fault it was working the whole time

walking through the debugger showed old data

thank you for your help